# Printing out a class objects variables from a stack

Tags: c++, class, stack

I am making a blackjack game as a means to practice.  I used an array at first, but decided to try to make a version using a stack since I could use the practice with stacks.

I created a playing card class.

```
class PlayingCard
{
   private: 
   int value;
   char suit;

   public:
   PlayingCard();

   PlayingCard(int val, char type)
   {
       value = val;
       suit = type;
   }

   int getValue()
   {
       return value;
   }

   char getSuit()
   {
      return suit;
   }

   void setValue(int val)
   {
      value = val;
   }

   void setSuit(char type)
   {
      suit = type;
   }
};
```

I then created a stack of that class.

```
stack<PlayingCard> deck1;
```

Now for example I push the following onto the stack:

```
deck1.push(PlayingCard('C', 9));
```

First, am I correct in my understanding that that pushes a PlayingCard object onto the stack with the suit of "C" (clubs) and a value of 9?

The issue I am having is now printing out the suit and value values when the player "draws a card" from the stack.

I can't just do "cout << deck1.top();" because it's a stack of class objects and the suit and value values are private variables of the playingCard which are retrieved with the get functions.

I tried making this function to print out the values instead:

```
void prints(PlayingCard tester)
{
    cout << tester.getSuit() << " " << tester.getValue() << "\n"; 
}
```

The call looks like this:

```
prints(deck1.top());
```

However that does not give me the correct output.  Any advice?  If I should just use a vector or an array then I guess I can do that but I thought it would be better to use a stack since a stack better mimics how an actual deck of cards would work with popping and drawing a card off the top of a deck.

Comment: verify `PlayingCard(int val, char type)` and `deck1.push(PlayingCard('C', 9));`

Comment: Are you seeing a "67" in your output - that is because you have the parameters in your constructor call the wrong way round.

Comment: Yes I was seeing a lot of 67s.  When I first ran the program I saw 67s and oddly enough, the actual symbols for the different card suits as opposed to the characters I had assigned for them.  Thank you and the other poster for pointing out the mix up.  Once I adjusted my constructor everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the more C++/OOP approach by adding to your class PlayingCard, a method "show()", as in:

```
class PlayingCard
{
   private: 
   int value;
   char suit;

public:
//...

std::string show()
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << "  " << value << "  " << suit << std::endl;
   return (ss.str());
}

// ... 
};
```

Then, in your code, after you have declared a deck, and put some cards into it ...

```
// ...

deck1.push(PlayingCard('C', 9));
// more cards ...

// to show the entire deck, you would want to be able to do something 
// like:
for (size_t i=0; i<deck1.size(); ++i)         // for each card
    std::cout << deck[i].show() << std::endl; // invoke show()
```

edit:

Oops.

Well, no, a stack is not a vector.  But the idea is the same ... spin thru each entry in your deck, and invoke the show method. As you have not finished your design, you will have to decide how to accomplish a visit to each stack item.

Comment: If this is the more correct approach / the approach that follows OOP best practices for C++ then I will definitely endeavor to switch over to this.  Are you implying that I should use an array instead of a stack (since I think you used an array in your example)?  EDIT:  Ah okay.  Gotcha.

Comment: I think the object you are printing should do it's own printing.  There is no reason for any other code to know what it means to print (or show()) a card. This is part of the sw engineering idea to minimize coupling, maximize cohesion.  Similarly, you should also consider overloading the operator << for your object.  Personally, I see no advantage of doing the overload because the method "show()"  returns a std::string, and all streams will know what do to with a string.

Comment: As to a vector vs a stack, I do not know where your design is headed.  A stack is a last-in-first-out structure and behavior.  If that is what fits the rest of your design, stay with the stack.  You might consider using a vector as an intermediate container when printing, but shuffling cards from one stack to another and back (to maintain order) would seem to work, too.

Comment: I have not seen it on a stack, but you might consider adding a new stack concept, perhaps.  Some way to visit each stack element, without emptying the stack.  Perhaps std::stack has such a thing, I don't remember at the moment.

Comment: My plan was to start with blackjack at first and then move on to more difficult card games like poker.  I really just used a stack because I thought  it would be most similar to an actual deck of cards and because I could use the practice with stacks.  Also, I got the show() function suggestion you posted to work.  I like it better than the public method I had previously used.  Thanks.

Comment: @Csw - I have thought of at least 1 reason to include in your stack study the writing an overload of the insert operator (<<).  See "setlocale(...)".  With the overloaded insert, a different locale (from the outer scope invocation) would be passed in to your insert (via the output stream, I think), perhaps allowing the same code to provide some foreign language accomodations, such as currency or calendar.  I have not yet done that.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

First, am I correct in my understanding that that pushes a PlayingCard object onto the stack with the suit of "C" (clubs) and a value of 9?

Looking at your function usage

```
deck1.push(PlayingCard('C', 9));
```

and definition

```
PlayingCard(int val, char type)
{
    value = val;
    suit = type;
}
```

It should be

```
deck1.push(PlayingCard(9, 'C'));
```

or change the function definition

```
PlayingCard(char type, int val)
```

Comment: Whoops.  Thank you for catching that screw up.  I changed the constructor quickly and ran it and now I am getting the correct output with my print function.

Answer (score 1):

verify `PlayingCard(int val, char type)` and `deck1.push(PlayingCard('C', 9));`

> I can't just do "cout << deck1.top();" because it's a stack of class objects and the suit and value values are private variables of the playingCard which are retrieved with the get functions.

Yes you can. Overload `operator <<`

```
class PlayingCard
{
    ...
    friend ostream & operator << (PlayingCard &card);
};
ostream &operator << (PlayingCard &card)
{
    out << tester.getSuit() << " " << tester.getValue();
    return out;
}

//cout << deck.top() << endl; should work
```

Comment: Is overloading the << operator preferable to making a print function like I did?  As in, is overloading the standard / best practice in this situation?  Thanks!

Comment: i think its neater to say `cout << card << endl;` than `print(card)`. Also, the former tells you explicitly to what stream the output is sent.